# There is a library on GitHub I would like to use in Java, It says I can use it by adding "dependency in your pom", what does this mean?

Tags: java, maven, github

I am new to Java and would like to use this https://github.com/fintrace/tspl2-driver

What is a pom? I've seen some things online about it being related to Maven but I am confused on how I actually can get and use this library and how to use Maven. Do I need to install Maven to use this library?

Thank you,

Comment: What are you using to write your Java program? How are you compiling and running it?

Comment: Yes, you need to download Maven and learn about how to configure a build in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: @KristofNeirynck I am using Eclipse

Comment: There are some good web tutorials - search for "eclipse maven tutorial" to get started. If you get stuck you can ask a more specific question (but check to see if there is already a relevant SO answer first - there probably will be).

Comment: You can start at [Welcome to Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html).